# (React Native) Changing order of views - bringing view to front

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, mobile, native

I'm using react-native-sketch library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sketch and I'm running into a few problems. I want to project a greyed out text and "write" on top of it, much like this.

[image]

The problem I'm having is with my current setup, I can write on the sketchview, but the text is "above" the sketchview, so I can't see any writing that's behind the textview. How can I move the text above the sketchview? Thanks!

```html
import Sketch from 'react-native-sketch';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { ScrollView,StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  save = () => { this.sketch.save().then(({ path }) => { Alert.alert('Image saved!', path); }); };

  render() {
  return (
  <View> 
      <CardView>
        <View>
        <Text> Draw </Text>
        <View> 
        <Sketch
          ref={sketch => { this.sketch = sketch; }}
          strokeColor="black"
          style = {styles.sketch}
          strokeThickness={3}> 
          <View> 
          <Text> text here </Text>
          </View>
        </Sketch> 
      </View>
        </View>
      </CardView>
      </View>

      );
    }
  }
```